# Webhook with an external jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set up a jenkins pipeline job with automatic github webhook and external jenkinsfile, but I'm having trouble setting everything up.

1) The jenkins job configuration for "project1" github repo is using "pipeline from SCM", but it's connected to "my-external-jenkinsfile" github repo. I would like to automatically trigger the job when a change is made on "project1" repo, but it's not working.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an error message? Which version of Jenkins are you using? Need more info.

Comment: I've been able to find a solution using "pipeline script" instead of "pipeline from SCM" and add my 2 repositories sources with pipeline help (using "scm" command)